# watching for changes in object state

Tags: c++, game-mechanics, state, objects

I'd like to know what others do to watch for changes in object states while the game is running.

Say you have an object and that object has a timer. The timer completes. What is the best way to know that the timer has completed?

something like?

- add all timers to a vector.

- set a bool when the timer completes

- loop over the vector continuously or at a short interval and watch for the bools?

Seems simple, but is it really that simple? What is the best way to loop over the vector continuously? C++11 thread and detach it from the main?

Comment: Why not go for an event like system? If there is a change you call the function that is registered to the event. C++11 has some new features for referencing function so that should be come in handy. Polling is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about instead of threads or continuous looping, you use an event system to notify listeners (people who care about when the timer/action is 'finished').

*Edit:* This pattern is called the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). There are many ways to implement the function callback system, including delegates and function pointers. It is up to you which one you use, though here is a resource on delegates: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13287/Fast-C-Delegate

**Advantages over continuous looping:**

1. Continuously looping means more code for calling classes (classes that use your objects), versus simply delegating a particular function as a handler with only the absolute minimum functionality contained within.
2. The object (or underlying timer, in this case) could very well be able to tell, much better than the calling classes can (or should), when the operation or action may complete. In this case, an event system could very well be more efficient. In addition, if your timer or action is itself a thread based process, then it will no longer have to check whether it is finished at all, logic flow will naturally result in completion and thus an event notification.

**Advantages over checking periodically:**

Checking periodically is only fine if the fact that the operation(or action) has completed has no implications for the rest of your game or other objects. For instance, doing this wouldn't be acceptable if you needed to respond instantly.

**Advantages over threads:**
Much of this is the same as continuous looping, but, one area where threads are superior to the other approaches, is, of course, the fact that they allow exceution to continue while checking is done. On the other hand, you may then need to perform locks etc and in this case I couldn't justify the extra complexity for such a simple process.

*Sidar: Beat me to it.*

Comment: is there a pattern that fits this? Or do you have a reference you can point to?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit that in. The observer pattern is what it is, though.

Comment: ah. I was just reading about that pattern.